Nested function doesn't call, why?
I am using Google sign in API in my project, and I try to call a function to post received credential to Backendless, but that function did not call, I used console.log function to check that, but it did not print, so function is not calling !
Code:
Google settings:
ngOnInit(): void {
    // @ts-ignore
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id: '205706621989-pken44sei0ti29vd95ukk3o2ja4e4gh1.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      callback: this.handleCredential
    });

}

login() {
    // @ts-ignore
    google.accounts.id.prompt();
}

handleCredential(response: { credential: string }) {
    this.authService.loginWithProvider(response.credential);
}

 loginWithProvider(credential: string) {
    console.log(credential); // this isn't calling

    this.http.post('https://brainyclub-eu.backendless.app/api/users/oauth/googleplus/login', {
      'accessToken': credential
    },
      {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
      }).subscribe((result) => {
        console.log(result);

   });
  }




Are there any errors in your console? Assuming it's your subscribe() that's not working, is ``this.http.post()` returning the expected value?

It worked using bind(),
ngOnInit(): void {
    // @ts-ignore
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id: '205706621989-pken44sei0ti29vd95ukk3o2ja4e4gh1.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      callback: this.handleCredential.bind(this)
    });

}

